# jQuery validation with next/prev button

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

here [Demo](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/KVLmjG)

Each block contains 5 Questions.**each block must fill and go to the next block.**

I tired the form are validate but it's go to the next block. I need to fill all values and go to the next Block.

In last block contain only submit button. 
**how to visible submit button last block.**

```
$('#nextBlock').click(function() {
    $('#register').valid();
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
        .next().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
        $('#nextBlock').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('#prevBlock').attr('disabled', null);
});
```

**I appreciate for your comment and review :)**

here my Updated Codepen:
**[Demo](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/qbGjym)**

i had another problem. its works only codepen. but in my html not working. Radio button are not validate. valid only Textbox

Comment: are you using jquery validation plugin

Comment: @ArunPJohny he is not checking valid() value as well as have not called validate(); before it too..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uhjLdnyo/3/

Comment: @ArunPJohny : i have added an answer about it before commenting here

Answer (score 1):

> `validate()` needs to be called on the form before checking it using
>   this method.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid

you should check the value of valid() after it;

```
 $('#register').validate()
if($('#register').valid()){
   // do the action
   }
```

[WORKING CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrVoJy)

```
$(function(){
$('#register').validate();
    $('#nextBlock').click(function() {

      if ($('#register').valid()) {
        $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
          .next().show().addClass('current');
        if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
          $('#nextBlock').attr('disabled', true);
        }
        $('#prevBlock').attr('disabled', null);
      }

    });

});
```

Comment: You have a `.valid()` before `.validate()`.  You also have `.validate()` inside of the `click()` handler function.  FYI - the `.validate()` method is only used for initializing the plugin and should be done on DOM ready, not inside a click handler.

Comment: @Sparky: you are right about the validate..it should be done on DOM ready and valid() before validate was just a typo :) thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the .valid() inside an if condition, it will return true if the field is validated and will only proceed to the next step:

```
$('#nextBlock').click(function() {
    if ($('#register').valid()) {
        $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
            .next().show().addClass('current');
        if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
            $('#nextBlock').attr('disabled', true);
        }
        $('#prevBlock').attr('disabled', null);
    }
});
```